# Googlemaps api v3: Markers not showing in Android Browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Morning,

I have created a mobile web app which plots multiple nearby locations on a Googlemap using API v3.

This works fine in Mobile Chrome, Mobile Firefox & Mobile Opera, but does not work properly in Androids native browser. In the latter, the markers are not shown. It does not give me error messages either.

The URI is 
    213.175.198.56/~webdesig/restaurants/

Here is the code:

```
<div id="map1" class="gmap"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map1, latlng1, options1;
    var distance = 2000;
    function initialize() {

        latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(localStorage.getItem("lat"), localStorage.getItem("long"));
        options1 = { zoom: 12, center: latlng1, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
        //map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), options1);
        map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), {
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                  center: latlng1,
                  zoom: 12
                });



        var request = {
                  location: latlng1,
                  radius: distance,
                  types: ['restaurant', 'cafe']
                };

                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map1);
                service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
        document.getElementById('showing').innerHTML = "Showing restaurants within "+distance+" metres of your location";
    }// initialize

    function callback(results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                  }
                }else{

                  alert('Unable to plot');
                }
              }



                // Function for adding a marker to the page.
        function addMarker(mylocation) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: mylocation,
                map: map1
            });
        }

              function createMarker(place) {
                var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;

                var request2 = { reference: place.reference };
                    service.getDetails(request2, function(details, status) {
                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                          var rating = details.rating;
                          if(!rating){rating = 'Not yet rated';}
                        infowindow.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address +"<br />Rating: "  +rating + "<br /><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"location.href='tel:" + details.formatted_phone_number+"'\" value=\"Call "+details.name+" \"/>");
                        infowindow.open(map1, this);
                      });
                    });

                var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                  'images/icons/restaurant.png',
                  new google.maps.Size(32,50),
                  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                  new google.maps.Point(16,50)
                );

                var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                  'images/icons/restaurantshadow.png',
                  new google.maps.Size(60,50),
                  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                  new google.maps.Point(16,50)
                );

                var shape = {
                  coord: [28,0,29,1,30,2,31,3,31,4,31,5,31,6,31,7,31,8,31,9,31,10,31,11,31,12,31,13,31,14,31,15,31,16,31,17,31,18,31,19,31,20,31,21,31,22,31,23,31,24,31,25,31,26,31,27,31,28,30,29,29,30,28,31,21,32,21,33,20,34,20,35,20,36,20,37,19,38,19,39,19,40,18,41,18,42,18,43,18,44,17,45,17,46,17,47,16,48,16,49,15,49,15,48,15,47,15,46,14,45,14,44,14,43,13,42,13,41,13,40,12,39,12,38,12,37,11,36,11,35,11,34,10,33,10,32,3,31,2,30,1,29,0,28,0,27,0,26,0,25,0,24,0,23,0,22,0,21,0,20,0,19,0,18,0,17,0,16,0,15,0,14,0,13,0,12,0,11,0,10,0,9,0,8,0,7,0,6,0,5,0,4,0,3,1,2,2,1,3,0,28,0],
                  type: 'poly'
                };

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  icon: image,
                  shadow: shadow,
                  shape: shape,
                  map: map1,
                  position: place.geometry.location
                });

                /*google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow.setContent(place.name+'<br/>'+place.formatted_address);
                  infowindow.open(map1, this);
                });*/
              }

    $('.page-map1').live("pagecreate", function() {

        initialize();
});

    $('.page-map1').live('pageshow',function(){

        //console.log("test");
        google.maps.event.trigger(map1, 'resize');
        map1.setOptions(options1); 
        // Testing the addMarker function
        here = new google.maps.LatLng(localStorage.getItem("lat"), localStorage.getItem("long"));
        addMarker(here);

    });


</script>
```

Comment: Really doesn't belong to android, since the code doesn't refer to Android developers, retagged :-) Good luck though :-)

Comment: Have tested in HTC Sensation, Samsung Galaxy Ace, Samsung Tab 2, it works in all but the HTC Sensation

Comment: maybe it doesn't have a browser that can give it location?

Comment: Anders, den har OperaMobile og Chrome mobile og den virker fint. It works fine in Opera Mobile and Chrome Mobile. It's just it's native browser where it isn't plotting markers on the HTC Sensation only.

Comment: Okay then it seems like an error in the native browser, or an unsupported feature. Try and see if it gets all the parameters that it requires through console.log, to narrow down where the error should be.